# Ubuntu 19.10 - endless black screen with an underscore on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10.

It boots fine. However, on shutdown, I get an endless black screen. The only thing visible is a white underscore in the upper left corner of the screen.

Previously, I had Win10 installed here. It had troubles shutting down as well - sometimes it did, sometimes it took quite a while, sometimes it didn't want to shut down whatsoever.
Earlier today, I tried to install Kubuntu, however it had multiple hiccups (from UI glitches, to refusing to boot at all, hanging on the first boot, and multiple error messages when shutting down). Whether it all is related I do not know.

Thank you for any advice!

Update:

- Pressing ESC does not do a thing.
- Also, when I'm booting Ubuntu from USB (the official image burnt onto an USB stick) the first line I'm reading is 'failed to claim resource '. The later part of the installation is going just fine, however.
- I'm using KDE. Logging out first via its GUI then shutting down works just fine. It's directly shutting down (whether via the KDE's GUI or via `shutdown -h now`) that causes the issue to appear.

Comment: Any more details when pressing ESC in such cases?

Comment: No, nothing happens.